# Can't Connect to MongoDB Atlas Cluster Using Mongo Shell

Tags: mongodb, shell, authentication, mongodb-atlas

I set up a cluster on MongoDB Atlas and made myself the admin but I'm having trouble connecting to the Cluster from the shell. On Atlas, I clicked the connect button, clicked connect with Mongo Shell, downloaded the latest Mongo Shell, and copied the command to connect to the cluster:

```
mongo "mongodb://testcluster-shard-00-00-acqhf.mongodb.net:27017,testcluster-shard-00-01-acqhf.mongodb.net:27017,testcluster-shard-00-02-acqhf.mongodb.net:27017/test?replicaSet=TestCluster-shard-0" --authenticationDatabase admin --ssl --username <USERNAME> --password <PASSWORD>
```

When I run this command I get the stream:

```
MongoDB shell version v3.4.10
connecting to: mongodb://testcluster-shard-00-00-
acqhf.mongodb.net:27017,testcluster-shard-00-01-
acqhf.mongodb.net:27017,testcluster-shard-00-02-
acqhf.mongodb.net:27017/test?replicaSet=TestCluster-shard-0
2017-11-20T11:58:31.883-0500 I NETWORK  [thread1] Starting new replica set monitor for TestCluster-shard-0/testcluster-shard-00-00-
acqhf.mongodb.net:27017,testcluster-shard-00-01-
acqhf.mongodb.net:27017,testcluster-shard-00-02-acqhf.mongodb.net:27017
2017-11-20T11:58:32.119-0500 I NETWORK  [thread1] Successfully connected to testcluster-shard-00-01-acqhf.mongodb.net:27017 (1 connections now open to testcluster-shard-00-01-acqhf.mongodb.net:27017 with a 5 second timeout)
2017-11-20T11:58:32.131-0500 I NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor-0] Successfully connected to testcluster-shard-00-00-acqhf.mongodb.net:27017 (1 connections now open to testcluster-shard-00-00-acqhf.mongodb.net:27017 with a 5 second timeout)
MongoDB server version: 3.4.10
2017-11-20T11:58:32.407-0500 I NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor-0] Successfully connected to testcluster-shard-00-02-acqhf.mongodb.net:27017 (1 connections now open to testcluster-shard-00-02-acqhf.mongodb.net:27017 with a 5 second timeout)
2017-11-20T11:58:32.497-0500 I NETWORK  [thread1] Marking host testcluster-shard-00-01-acqhf.mongodb.net:27017 as failed :: caused by :: Location8000: can't authenticate against replica set node testcluster-shard-00-01-acqhf.mongodb.net:27017: bad auth Authentication failed.
2017-11-20T11:58:32.639-0500 I NETWORK  [thread1] Successfully connected to testcluster-shard-00-02-acqhf.mongodb.net:27017 (1 connections now open to testcluster-shard-00-02-acqhf.mongodb.net:27017 with a 0 second timeout)
2017-11-20T11:58:32.756-0500 I NETWORK  [thread1] Marking host testcluster-shard-00-02-acqhf.mongodb.net:27017 as failed :: caused by :: Location8000: can't authenticate against replica set node testcluster-shard-00-02-acqhf.mongodb.net:27017: bad auth Authentication failed.
2017-11-20T11:58:32.899-0500 I NETWORK  [thread1] Successfully connected to testcluster-shard-00-00-acqhf.mongodb.net:27017 (1 connections now open to testcluster-shard-00-00-acqhf.mongodb.net:27017 with a 0 second timeout)
2017-11-20T11:58:32.995-0500 I NETWORK  [thread1] Marking host testcluster-shard-00-00-acqhf.mongodb.net:27017 as failed :: caused by :: Location8000: can't authenticate against replica set node testcluster-shard-00-00-acqhf.mongodb.net:27017: bad auth Authentication failed.
2017-11-20T11:58:33.100-0500 I NETWORK  [thread1] Marking host testcluster-shard-00-01-acqhf.mongodb.net:27017 as failed :: caused by :: Location8000: can't authenticate against replica set node testcluster-shard-00-01-acqhf.mongodb.net:27017: bad auth Authentication failed.
2017-11-20T11:58:33.101-0500 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: can't authenticate against replica set node testcluster-shard-00-01-acqhf.mongodb.net:27017: bad auth Authentication failed. :
DB.prototype._authOrThrow@src/mongo/shell/db.js:1461:20
@(auth):6:1
@(auth):1:2
exception: login failed
```

I replace the  and  with my username and password but I still can't connect. Do I need to have mongod running in the background? If not what do I need to do to successfully connect? Thank you.

Comment: username or password is wrong. Try to create another user in atlas `clusters/security/users`. If you can reliable replicate it, contact atlas support.

Answer (score 20):

I had to create a new user with a different username and password, and when I ran the command with these new credentials I could connect.

Comment: same here .. it does not make sense though

Comment: Same here. +1 to "has no sense"

Comment: I think the correct answer is the other one which explains there is an update delay

Comment: It makes sense, MongoDB Atlas asks you to create a user when the database is being created and there seems to be a mismatch. I created a new user after the database was alive and was able to connect straight away.

Comment: same here. Recreate username and password with the same one as before one.

Answer (score 3):

My problem was that I had only recently set / changed the password in the Atlas UI - it takes a minute or so for them to deploy any changes, even password resets etc.  I was able to login once I waited for the changes to be deployed

Answer (score 2):

Same as others, did not like my pw.  Worked fine from the command line, but not from Compass.  Checking the troubleshooting page https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/troubleshoot-connection/#special-characters-in-connection-string-password.  I had special characters in my pw.  Tried escaping them, then just went back and reset my password to something simple w/o special characters - took a minute, but then I connected easily.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove special character from your password.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes is worth reseting the local service. Run `brew services stop mongodb-community` and then `brew services start mongodb-community`.

Comment: Not sure if MacOS is mentioned anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, go-to network access and edit it to be accessed from any where which is IP 0.0.0.0/0 and make sure you are not using a VPN software which makes the connection slow and timeout.